# How to avoid loading duplicate objects into main memory?

Tags: java, c#, sql, oop, design-patterns

Suppose I am using SQL and I have two tables. One is Company, the other is Employee. Naturally, the employee table has a foreign key referencing the company he or she works for.

When I am using this data set in my code, I'd like to know what company each employee works for. The best solution I've thought of it to add an instance variable to my Employee class called Company (of type Company). This variable may be lazy-loaded, or populated manually.

The problem is that many employees work for the same company, and so each employee would end up storing a completely identical copy of the Company object, unnecessarily. This could be a big issue if something about the Company needs to be updated. Also, the Company object would naturally store a list of its employees, therefore I could also run into the problem of having an infinite circular reference.

What should I be doing differently? It seems object oriented design doesn't work very well with relational data.

This is more of a design/principles sort of question, I do not have any specific code, I am just looking for a step in the right direction!

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: If you cache the Company and reference the same instance there is no duplicate at all.

Comment: Just an addition to @Gusman comment, you would like to use hash based collection for storing these references. Also, depending on your application it might be concurrent collection.

Comment: @Karolis Is this the normal solution to this issue? I've never seen this used anywhere, so I'd assume there is a more typical solution, considering nearly every application on the planet that uses SQL may run into this issue.

Comment: You should use an ORM framework (I know about Java ones), such as Hibernate, Ebean, ActiveJDBC, etc. If you don't want or can't use an ORM framework, you should use your objects as objects and not as data values, i.e. if company Acme has id=1, there should exist only one instance of Company with that id, no matter if many instances of Employee have a reference to that company. There are many techniques to achieve this, designing a persistence layer is hard...

Comment: OOP was never meant for modeling and representing data. Data is supposed to be encapsulated or passed as messages. Objects should be designed around system services and responsibilities. What you're doing is equivalent to constructing a car based on a road map. Don't conflate domain model entities with system objects/services.

Comment: @reaanb Well this is the real world, I can't always decide what sort of data I am dealing with.

Comment: What I think he is trying to say is that you should be writing your models as representations of the data that you need. If you NEED all of the information about all employees, and you need all of the information about all of the companies that they are related to, than write a model for it. Otherwise, write your model to facilitate the needed data for the business application at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try design your business objects to mirror database schema.
Design objects to serve your business requirements.

For example in case when you need to display list of employees without company information, you can create function which retrieve only required information from database to the object

```
public class EmployeeBasicInfo
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

For next requirements you need a list of employees with full information  - then you will have function which retrieve full data from database

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public CompanyBasicInfo Company;
}
```

Where `Company` class will not have collection of employees, but will have only information required for `Employee` class.

```
public class CompanyBasicInfo 
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

Of course in last case you end up with bunch of different `Company` objects which will have same data. But it should be Ok.

If you afraid that having same copy of data in different object will cause a performance problem, it will not until you will load millions of employees - which should be good sign of something gone wrong in your application design.

Of course in situation where you actually need to load millions of employees - then you can use approach that class which loads employees - will first load all companies in the `Map<int, Company>`, and then when loading employees you will refer same `Company` instance for employees.

Comment: So if the Employer/Company class also does the same and stores a list of Employees,  couldn't this cause a huge issue (infinite recursion)? Employee stores Company, which stores a duplicate of Employee, which stores a duplicate of Company, which stores a 2nd duplicate of Employee which stores a 2nd duplicate of Company etc. forever until the your computer runs out of memory and crashes. Any way to avoid this without caching? Maybe I'm just doing something fundamentally wrong?

Comment: @sausageberg You are storing reference nothing more, just a link to certain memory block. That is how graphs work and numerous other common collection types. But you either store new value for every entry or you cache it, I do not see any other option as of right now.

Comment: @Karolis Without caching, it would store more than the reference, it would be duplicating the object itself. Am I really the only person who is running into this issue? There must be some way to do this without relying on lazy-loading every property.

Comment: @sausageberg, the idea that you create objects which will serve only one specific requirement. For displaying list of employees with company information `CompanyBasicInfo` class don't need to have collection of employees in it.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I really the only person who is running into this issue? There must be some way to do this without relying on lazy-loading every property.

This problem has been solved many times before already. Avoid re-inventing the wheel by using any of the widely available ORM frameworks.

In a database table, the primary key identifies a record; in a running application, the reference tracks an object; and, at an even lower abstraction, a memory address points to the bytes that represent that object.

When you initialise an object and assign it to a variable, the variable is sufficient to track the object in memory so that you can subsequently access it. However, in the database layer, a primary key is needed to locate the record in a database table. Therefore, to bridge the gap between the relational model and the object model, the artificial identifier property is required in your object.